# Get SOAP element by tag with namespace in Java

Tags: java, soap

I wondered how it was possible to get the content of a SOAP response body child when the child tag looks like this:

`<sth:x>...</sth:x>`

In the Oracle docs I found how to [loop all Elements with a specific name](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19340-01/820-6767/aeqex/index.html).
But therefore I need to create an Element first that specifies the name of the tag I want to search.

How do I create an element looking like the one above? I know how to make one like this:

```
<sth:id sth="asdf">
```

But that doesn't really work.
Here is the server-response I attempt to read.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <ns5:loginResponse xmlns:ns5="x">
            <ns5:id>Value I am looking for</ns5:id>
            <ns5:rc>0</ns5:rc>
        </ns5:loginResponse>
     </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
String xml = "YourXMl";
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
InputSource is = new InputSource(new StringReader(xml));
Document doc = builder.parse(is);
NodeList nodes =  doc.getDocumentElement().getElementsByTagNameNS("x","id");
System.err.println(nodes.item(0).getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue());
```

There are two important things `factory.setNamespaceAware(true);` - to turn on support for xml namespaces.
`doc.getDocumentElement().getElementsByTagNameNS("x","id");` To get element using namespace uri and element name. And here is `<ns5:loginResponse xmlns:ns5="x">` declaration of namespace uri. `x` is uri `ns5` is namespace.

Comment: I tried but I get the following error:

`org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed in prolog.`

Also do you know a way to read the answer using the SOAP API?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer:

The Element in question was within another SOAPBodyElement.
So looping through both elements gave me the correct Value:

```
body = reply.getSOAPBody();
Iterator replyIt = body.getChildElements();

while(replyIt.hasNext()){
    SOAPBodyElement replysbe = (SOAPBodyElement) replyIt.next();
    Iterator replyIt2 = replysbe.getChildElements();
    SOAPElement sentSE = (SOAPElement) replyIt2.next();
    sessionID = sentSE.getValue();
}
```